# FromArgb vs FromScRgb

Tags: c#, wpf

Should these two expressions result in colors which are roughly the same?

```
Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, (byte)0.25 * 255))

Color.FromScRgb(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.25f))
```

This test program demonstrates that they show up with seemingly different alpha values:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace Test_FromArgb_FromScRbg
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var panel = new StackPanel();

            Content = panel;

            panel.Children.Add(
                new Rectangle()
                {
                    Width = 100,
                    Height = 100,
                    Fill = new SolidColorBrush(
                        Color.FromArgb(
                            255, 
                            255, 
                            255, 
                            (byte)0.25 * 255))
                });

            panel.Children.Add(
                new Rectangle()
                {
                    Width = 100,
                    Height = 100,
                    Fill = new SolidColorBrush(
                        Color.FromScRgb(
                            1.0f,
                            1.0f,
                            1.0f,
                            0.25f))
                });
        }
    }
}
```

Here's what the demo program looks like on my system:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic reason behind this is mentioned by mzzzzb above:

> the scale 0.0 - 1.0 does not map linearly to 0 - 255

I.e. the ScRgb components do not map linearly to the Argb components.

Comment: What is the mapping like then - some kind of gamma curve?

Answer (score 1):

from the docs i can see that the last argument is actually the blue component that you are modifying, alpha is same; fully opaque for both colors

`(byte) 0.25 * 255` will give you `0` blue for `0.25` is cast to `byte` before multiplication, so first one is effectively `RGB(255, 255, 0)` which is pure yellow. you ought to do `(byte) (0.25 * 255)` which will be `RGB(255, 255, 63)`

when took the second color to paint i found out that it is actually `RGB(255, 255, 140)`. so it seems that the scale 0.0 - 1.0 does not map linearly to 0 - 255.

Comment: Aha... that they don't map linearly is indeed the issue here. Thanks mzzzzb!

Comment: Wrong even with 63 ((byte) (0.25 * 255)) doesn't match the same color.

Comment: yup, the the float scale does not map linearly to the int 0-255 scale. @FurqanSafdar the solution you have given may be correct. but thats not the point here, the thing is that -- intuitively we assume them to be linearly related. 

btw how did you get to that solution

Comment: You are right because i tried this same solution at my side before answering to this question but the results where still the same. So after little research on web i got to this perfect solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `ColorFloatToByte` method to have your desired results:

```
private static byte ColorFloatToByte(float val)
{
    if (!(val > 0.0)) // Handles NaN case too
        return (0);
    else if (val <= 0.0031308)
        return ((byte)((255.0f * val * 12.92f) + 0.5f));
    else if (val < 1.0)
        return ((byte)((255.0f * ((1.055f * 
               (float)Math.Pow((double)val, (1.0 / 2.4))) - 0.055f)) + 0.5f));
    else
        return (255);
}
```

Usage:

```
Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, ColorFloatToByte(0.25f)))

Color.FromScRgb(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.25f))
```

Answer (score 0):

Same answer as already mentioned - they do not map linearly ( they are different colour spaces - ScRGB is not SRGB with higher precision )

To mzzzzb "@FurqanSafdar the solution you have given may be correct. but thats not the point here, the thing is that -- intuitively we assume them to be linearly related. btw how did you get to that solution"

( We all know what assume does. )  Perhaps it would have been better to link to the definitions of sRGB and ScRGB !  Also, given that they are different color spaces with different ranges, why would you assume ?

You can see the source code and what is being performed:

[FromScRGB](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationCore/Core/CSharp/System/Windows/Media/Color.cs,7244816b6f563fc2,references)

[FromArgb](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationCore/Core/CSharp/System/Windows/Media/Color.cs,9289c34fb9030bfd,references)

In particular the conversion functions:

[ScRgbTosRgb](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationCore/Core/CSharp/System/Windows/Media/Color.cs,e72f34a7df9ac7d2,references)

[sRgbToScRgb](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationCore/Core/CSharp/System/Windows/Media/Color.cs,13c664241d9cf253)

The ScRgbTosRgb function is the ColorFloatToByte mentioned by Furqan Safdar.