# Drawing a gradient from dataset

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there an easy way to draw a gradient line, where the color ratio is shifting along the line? The thickness of the line (the gradient width) will not be constant. A 2-D dataset will be available and somehow describing the gradient path.

Have a look at the rainbow image attached, but please note that the black lines are not relevant for the question.

[image: Gradient from dataset]

Comment: start coding with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30339553/fill-panel-with-gradient-in-three-colors) and combine with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12108534/drawing-a-polygon-according-to-the-input-coordinates). Easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an array as source for the "Temperature" of the given value.

For Example:

```
 private static Color[] colors = 
{
    Color.FromArgb(155, 188, 255), //    40000
    Color.FromArgb(155, 188, 255), //    39500
    Color.FromArgb(155, 188, 255), //    39000
    Color.FromArgb(155, 188, 255), //    38500
    Color.FromArgb(156, 188, 255), //    38000
    Color.FromArgb(156, 188, 255), //    37500
    Color.FromArgb(156, 189, 255), //    37000
    Color.FromArgb(156, 189, 255), //    36500
    Color.FromArgb(156, 189, 255), //    36000
    Color.FromArgb(157, 189, 255), //    35500
    Color.FromArgb(157, 189, 255), //    35000
    Color.FromArgb(157, 189, 255), //    34500
    Color.FromArgb(157, 189, 255), //    34000
    Color.FromArgb(157, 189, 255), //    33500
    Color.FromArgb(158, 190, 255), //    33000
    Color.FromArgb(158, 190, 255), //    32500
    Color.FromArgb(158, 190, 255), //    32000
    Color.FromArgb(158, 190, 255), //    31500
    Color.FromArgb(159, 190, 255), //    31000
    Color.FromArgb(159, 190, 255), //    30500
    Color.FromArgb(159, 191, 255), //    30000
    Color.FromArgb(159, 191, 255), //    29500
    Color.FromArgb(160, 191, 255), //    29000
    Color.FromArgb(160, 191, 255), //    28500
    Color.FromArgb(160, 191, 255), //    28000
    Color.FromArgb(161, 192, 255), //    27500
    Color.FromArgb(161, 192, 255), //    27000
    Color.FromArgb(161, 192, 255), //    26500
    Color.FromArgb(162, 192, 255), //    26000
    Color.FromArgb(162, 193, 255), //    25500
    Color.FromArgb(163, 193, 255), //    25000
    Color.FromArgb(163, 193, 255), //    24500
    Color.FromArgb(163, 194, 255), //    24000
    Color.FromArgb(164, 194, 255), //    23500
    Color.FromArgb(164, 194, 255), //    23000
    Color.FromArgb(165, 195, 255), //    22500
    Color.FromArgb(166, 195, 255), //    22000
    Color.FromArgb(166, 195, 255), //    21500
    Color.FromArgb(167, 196, 255), //    21000
    Color.FromArgb(168, 196, 255), //    20500
    Color.FromArgb(168, 197, 255), //    20000
    Color.FromArgb(169, 197, 255), //    19500
    Color.FromArgb(170, 198, 255), //    19000
    Color.FromArgb(171, 198, 255), //    18500
    Color.FromArgb(172, 199, 255), //    18000
    Color.FromArgb(173, 200, 255), //    17500
    Color.FromArgb(174, 200, 255), //    17000
    Color.FromArgb(175, 201, 255), //    16500
    Color.FromArgb(176, 202, 255), //    16000
    Color.FromArgb(177, 203, 255), //    15500
    Color.FromArgb(179, 204, 255), //    15000
    Color.FromArgb(180, 205, 255), //    14500
    Color.FromArgb(182, 206, 255), //    14000
    Color.FromArgb(184, 207, 255), //    13500
    Color.FromArgb(186, 208, 255), //    13000
    Color.FromArgb(188, 210, 255), //    12500
    Color.FromArgb(191, 211, 255), //    12000
    Color.FromArgb(193, 213, 255), //    11500
    Color.FromArgb(196, 215, 255), //    11000
    Color.FromArgb(200, 217, 255), //    10500  
    Color.FromArgb(204, 219, 255), //    10000
    Color.FromArgb(208, 222, 255), //    9500
    Color.FromArgb(214, 225, 255), //    9000
    Color.FromArgb(220, 229, 255), //    8500
    Color.FromArgb(227, 233, 255), //    8000
    Color.FromArgb(235, 238, 255), //    7500
    Color.FromArgb(245, 243, 255), //    7000
    Color.FromArgb(255, 249, 253), //    6500
    Color.FromArgb(255, 243, 239), //    6000
    Color.FromArgb(255, 236, 224), //    5500
    Color.FromArgb(255, 228, 206), //    5000
    Color.FromArgb(255, 219, 186), //    4500
    Color.FromArgb(255, 209, 163), //    4000
    Color.FromArgb(255, 196, 137), //    3500
    Color.FromArgb(255, 180, 107), //    3000
    Color.FromArgb(255, 161,  72), //    2500
    Color.FromArgb(255, 137,  18), //    2000
    Color.FromArgb(255, 109,   0), //    1500 
    Color.FromArgb(255,  51,   0), //    1000
};
```

(Source: [Display temperature as a color with C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229895/display-temperature-as-a-color-with-c))

with this source you can divide your values in 79 colors.

The rest is just drawing pixel per pixel for each value in your dataset.

Code Example:

```
public Color getPixelColor(double value) {
    return colors[(int)(value / range)];
}

public void drawPixel(double value, int x, int y) {
    Brush aBrush = new SolidColorBrush(getPixelColor(value));
    Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
    g.FillRectangle(aBrush, x, y, 1, 1);
}
```